# How do I authorise users in Laravel Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-sanctum

New to Livewire. I saw in the [Livewire docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/security) that you can use `$this->authorize()` alongside Policies to validate certain actions.

My question is, what user am I authorizing exactly?

I'm using Laravel Sanctum for authentication, and normally I'd have the token passed into an `Authorization` header, which is read in a Request. But how would that be done in this case? At what point is the authenticated user defined?

Or am I doing it completely wrong?

Currently, I have a `LoginForm` component with the following function:

```php
public function submit(UserService $userService)
{
    $response = $userService->auth(
        $this->only(['email', 'password'])
    );

    if (! $response['success']) {
        session()->flash('error', $response['message']);

        return $this->redirectRoute('login');
    }

    // Store access token
    session('token', $response['token']);

    return $this->redirectRoute('home')  ;
}
```

I then use the `session('token')` within the code to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does say it's a method of the Livewire component but to understand how it works take a look at the Laravel docs: [Authorizing Actions Using Policies > Via Controller Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers).

> Laravel provides a helpful authorize method to any of your controllers which extend the `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` base class.
>
> Like the `can` method, this method accepts the name of the action you wish to authorize and the relevant model. If the action is not authorized, the authorize method will throw an Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException exception

Looking at the source code we can see `authorise` is a wrapper for the `Gate::authorise` function:

```
public function authorize($ability, $arguments = [])
{
    [$ability, $arguments] = $this->parseAbilityAndArguments($ability, $arguments);

    return app(Gate::class)->authorize($ability, $arguments);
}
```

In the documentation for [Authorizing Actions](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates) it says:

> Note that you are not required to pass the currently authenticated user to these methods. Laravel will automatically take care of passing the user into the gate closure.

So in answer to the question "what user am I authorizing exactly?" it is the **currently authenticated** user.

If there is no authenticated user the `authorize` function throws an `AuthorizationException` exception just as if they are not permitted to perform that action.

If you want to check a user other than the currently authenticated user, use the `forUser` method on the Gate facade::

```
if (Gate::forUser($user)->allows('update-post', $post)) {
    // The user can update the post...
}
```